# Can a View necessarily have only one ViewModel in android?

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

i'm studying `android`.

I know a `ViewModel` can have `multiple views` (`n:1`)

But what about the other way around?

I saw somewhere that `views` and `viewmodels` should also be `1:1`.

For example, suppose we have `fragments A, B, C (views)` and the following situation:

`A` and `B` pass data through the `SharedViewModel`. (`from A to B`)

And `C` and `B` also pass data through the `SharedViewModel` (`from C to A`).

`A` and `B` have a common `viewmodel`.

`B` and `C` have a common `viewmodel`.

If so, then `B` has `two viewmodels`.

when seeing this
Can a view have `multiple viewmodels`?

Isn't it necessary to have only one viewmodel per view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no requirements for `Fragments` to have just 1 `ViewModel`.

Usually you have at least 2, the activity one (accessible to all child fragments) and the fragment one but there is no limit except that having multiple `ViewModel`s for the same fragment increases the business logic complexity and should be avoided.

If you check a Google reference app like [iosched](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/b0c6384b4b26efdac16142b8e85b1d8859053a48/mobile/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/settings/SettingsFragment.kt#L43-L44) you can see that they use the fragment one and the activity one (where needed).

If you use the single Activity pattern it would be easier, more info in this [GoogleIO/2018 video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2k8x8V77CrU)

Comment: good point on Activity shared Viewmodel